# 32bit / 64bit DOS Available

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, disk-operating-system

Is there any 32bit / 64bit DOS Available?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "DOS" - do you want a MS-DOS-compatible system, or just one with the same appearance, or just any "disk operating system"?

Answer (score 7):

http://www.freedos.org/

Comment: "possibility of writing 32-bit protected mode drivers (JLMs=Jemm Loadable Module) "

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/freedos/index.php?title=Main_Page#Features

Does that count as 32-bit support?

Answer (score 5):

I think this might answer your question:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS/4GW

Comment: Well, it's (arguably) 32bit, but definitely not 64bit...